Static custom claims from Microsoft Entra ID
I have an application on Microsoft Entra ID with static attributes for custom claims but I'm unable to get those claims in the access token.
I have updated the manifest file:
{
    "acceptMappedClaims": true,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
}

But still I'm not getting custom claims defined in the application.
I tried adding custom claims manually in the Manifest file but values cannot be given for custom claim.

Hi, I have identified issue and found that claim values are received in ID Token instead of Access Token.


I have an application on Microsoft Entra ID with static attributes for custom claims but I'm unable to get those claims in the access token.

In my environment, I created policy with below powershell script.
Script:
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/employeeid","JwtClaimType":"staffid"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "staffid" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolic

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy  -RefObjectId 'PolicyID' -Id 'ServicePrincipalObjID'

Command and output:
PS C:\Users\xxxxx> New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/employeeid","JwtClaimType":"staffid"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "staffid" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

Id                                   DisplayName Type                IsOrganizationDefault
--                                   ----------- ----                ---------------------
02dxxxxxx19xxxae16f7a staffid     ClaimsMappingPolicy False                

PS C:\Users\vxxxxu> Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy  -RefObjectId '02d1289e-9xxxxxx7a' -Id '9e4fd06dxxxxxx46-43a712de6e21'
PS C:\Users\xxxxu> 

Now, I assigned it to the user with request like below:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
{
    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute1": "EMP456728"
    }
}


According to this MS-Document,
To display custom claims in access token you need to generate the token for your application with custom Api scope from app registration.
Portal:

Now when I generate the tokens via Postman by using below parameters:
Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : FrontEndClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: api://efxxxxxxxx5a9c4ccf/sample.read openid

I got both access token and id token from the above request.

Now, when I decoded the access token, I can be able to get the claim values.

